# Django Admin exclude model from index and app page

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I want to hide some models from admin index page and app page. For example, these that I have visible in `inlines` as related objects.
One more point, I want to keep the ability to work with `change_view` and `add_view`, but not `list_view` of that model.

Tried to find any hints in `admin/templates/admin/*.html` files, but haven't found anything helpful.

Is it possible without "hacks", monkey-patching and external libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_module_permission) tells:

> [ModelAdmin.**has_module_permission**(request)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_module_permission)
> Should return True if displaying the module on the admin index page and accessing the module’s index page is permitted, False otherwise. Uses User.has_module_perms() by default. Overriding it does not restrict access to the view, add, change, or delete views.

To avoid removal all permissions (like with `get_model_perms()`) you can redefine **`has_module_permission()`** method to always `return False`.

```py
@admin.register(SomeModel)
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

this will hide the model from the index

```
class YourModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_model_perms(self, request):    
        return {}  # return empty

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

more about Django admin
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: Looks like what I need. Can you explain how it works and what else it can affect? For me, it looks that it can remove some permission which should be there.

Comment: This removes all permissions, but to exclude only from index page - we can use `has_module_permission` - see answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/65887364/3722635